# Can you edit the tags of a registered model version after the fact using mlflow api?

Tags: python, mlflow

I am trying to use the mlflow model registry. My plan is to have a monthly scheduled retraining pipeline. I know from reading the documentation that so long as I set the model name to the same string if I save a model/use create_model_version it will create a new version of the model. I also saw from the documentation that I can set the tags associated with a version using create_model_version as well. I want to set tags for valid_to_date and valid_from_date for each version so that if I want to go back in time and backfill predictions with the correct version *as of* when the data is from I am using the correct model. My initial thought was every time I create a new model version I set the valid_from_date as the date of that model version creation and the valid_to_date as 1-1-2099. Then when I train a new version edit the tag of the previous version valid_to_date from 1-1-2099 to the date it was superceded by a new version. Is that something that can be done using the mlflow python api?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!

```
client = MlflowClient()
client.set_model_version_tag(
  name=<model_name>,
  version=<model_version>,
  key=<Tag_Key>,
  value=<Tag_Value>
)
```